# Convert Array php to json

Tags: php, json

I want to post this array to website using curl, so I must convert it first to json. I used json_encode but I got the wrong format.

```
   $inv=Array
    ("sales_invoice" => Array
            (
                "transaction_date" => $date,
                "transaction_lines_attributes" => [ Array
                    (
                                "quantity" => 1,
                                "rate" => $price,
                                "discount" => 0,
                                "product_name" => "$ordersku",
                                "tax" => false
                    )],
                "address" => "JL. Gatot Subroto 55, Jakarta, Jawa Barat, 11739",
                "term_name" => "Net 30",
                "deposit_to_name" => "Cash",
                "warehouse_name" => "",
                "due_date" => "$due2",
                "shipping_date" => "$date",
                "shipping_price" => "0.0",
                "shipping_address" => "ship_address",
                "is_shipped" => true,
                "ship_via" => "jne",
                "reference_no" => "$ordernumber",
                "tracking_no" => "",
                "deposit" => "0",
                "person_name" => "Lazada",
                "discount_type_name" => "Value",
                "discount_unit" => 0,
                "custom_id" => "",
                "tax_name" => "Tax 0%",
                "email" => "milleniabedding@gmail.com",
                "transaction_no" => "$orderitemid",
            ));
```

the json format must be like this

```
{\n  \"sales_invoice\": {\n    \"transaction_date\": \"2015-10-23\",\n    \"transaction_lines_attributes\": [\n      {\n        \"quantity\": 1,\n        \"rate\": 25000000,\n        \"discount\": 0,\n        \"product_name\": \"Sales\",\n        \"tax\": true\n      }\n    ],\n    \"address\": \"JL. Gatot Subroto 55, Jakarta, Jawa Barat, 11739\",\n    \"term_name\": \"Cash_on_Delivery\",\n    \"deposit_to_name\": \"Cash\",\n    \"warehouse_name\": \"New Warehouse\",\n    \"due_date\": \"2015-10-23\",\n    \"shipping_date\": \"2016-09-15\",\n    \"shipping_price\": \"0.0\",\n    \"shipping_address\": \"ship_address\",\n    \"is_shipped\": true,\n    \"ship_via\": \"jne\",\n    \"reference_no\": \"REF1\",\n    \"tracking_no\": \"TR01\",\n    \"deposit\": \"25000000\",\n    \"person_name\": \"Per\",\n    \"discount_type_name\": \"Value\",\n    \"discount_unit\": 30000,\n    \"custom_id\": \"SalesInvoice1\",\n    \"tax_name\": \"PPN Tes\",\n    \"email\": \"sale@example.com\",\n    \"transaction_no\": \"4SH4LFS\"\n  }\n}";
```

Cheers

Comment: If you want another output structure then you need to change the structure of your array.

Comment: are `"$ordernumber"` and `"$orderitemid"` strings of the values inside `$ordernumber` and `$orderitemid`, at the moment i'm assuming the latter

Comment: @Rizier123 how to change the arrays structure so the json will be like that format?

Comment: @GalihAbdullah Just decode the json you want and you see what structure you need.

Answer (score 1):

90% of this can be done with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) as i have shown [here](https://repl.it/EKI5)

```
$price  = 15.50;
$ordersku   = "TEST_SKU";
$due2   = "due?";
$date   = "2015-10-23";
$ordernumber    = "1900000001";
$orderitemid    = "1500";

$inv=array("sales_invoice" => array
        (
            "transaction_date" => $date,
            "transaction_lines_attributes" => [ array
                (
                            "quantity" => 1,
                            "rate" => $price,
                            "discount" => 0,
                            "product_name" => "$ordersku",
                            "tax" => false
                )],
            "address" => "JL. Gatot Subroto 55, Jakarta, Jawa Barat, 11739",
            "term_name" => "Net 30",
            "deposit_to_name" => "Cash",
            "warehouse_name" => "",
            "due_date" => "$due2",
            "shipping_date" => "$date",
            "shipping_price" => "0.0",
            "shipping_address" => "ship_address",
            "is_shipped" => true,
            "ship_via" => "jne",
            "reference_no" => "$ordernumber",
            "tracking_no" => "",
            "deposit" => "0",
            "person_name" => "Lazada",
            "discount_type_name" => "Value",
            "discount_unit" => 0,
            "custom_id" => "",
            "tax_name" => "Tax 0%",
            "email" => "milleniabedding@gmail.com",
            "transaction_no" => "$orderitemid",
        ));

$json = json_encode($inv);

$replacement = array(
    "search" =>  array("{",  "}",  '"', ","),
    "replace" => array('{\n','}\n','\"',',\n')
    );

var_dump(str_replace($replacement["search"],$replacement["replace"],$json));
```

the result of the `str_replace` is

```
{\n\"sales_invoice\":{\n\"transaction_date\":\"2015-10-23\",\n\"transaction_lines_attributes\":[{\n\"quantity\":1,\n\"rate\":15.5,\n\"discount\":0,\n\"product_name\":\"TEST_SKU\",\n\"tax\":false}\n],\n\"address\":\"JL. Gatot Subroto 55,\n Jakarta,\n Jawa Barat,\n 11739\",\n\"term_name\":\"Net 30\",\n\"deposit_to_name\":\"Cash\",\n\"warehouse_name\":\"\",\n\"due_date\":\"due?\",\n\"shipping_date\":\"2015-10-23\",\n\"shipping_price\":\"0.0\",\n\"shipping_address\":\"ship_address\",\n\"is_shipped\":true,\n\"ship_via\":\"jne\",\n\"reference_no\":\"1900000001\",\n\"tracking_no\":\"\",\n\"deposit\":\"0\",\n\"person_name\":\"Lazada\",\n\"discount_type_name\":\"Value\",\n\"discount_unit\":0,\n\"custom_id\":\"\",\n\"tax_name\":\"Tax 0%\",\n\"email\":\"milleniabedding@gmail.com\",\n\"transaction_no\":\"1500\"}\n}\n
```

you simply create your normal json string and then using `str_replace` add in the `\` where you need it. problem is that this method wont insert those spaces/tabs for you.

### if you really need those tabs then the best way to do this is with recursion

```
function altJSonEncode($arr,$tabNo=1)
{
    $returnStr = "";
    $genTabs = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $tabNo; $i++)
    {
        $genTabs .= "  ";   
    }
    foreach($arr as $key => $val)
    {
        $returnStr .= $genTabs.'\"'.$key.'\": ';
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            $tabNo += 1;
            $returnStr .= altJSonEncode($val,$tabNo);
        }
        else
        {
            $returnStr .= '\"'.$val.'\",\n';
        }
    }
    return '{\n'.$genTabs.$returnStr.$genTabs.'}\n';
}

$price  = 25000000;
$ordersku   = "Sales";
$due2   = "2015-10-23";
$date   = "2015-10-23";
$ordernumber    = "1900000001";
$orderitemid    = "1500";

$inv=array("sales_invoice" => array
        (
            "transaction_date" => $date,
            "transaction_lines_attributes" => [ array
                (
                            "quantity" => 1,
                            "rate" => $price,
                            "discount" => 0,
                            "product_name" => "$ordersku",
                            "tax" => false
                )],
            "address" => "JL. Gatot Subroto 55, Jakarta, Jawa Barat, 11739",
            "term_name" => "Net 30",
            "deposit_to_name" => "Cash",
            "warehouse_name" => "",
            "due_date" => "$due2",
            "shipping_date" => "$date",
            "shipping_price" => "0.0",
            "shipping_address" => "ship_address",
            "is_shipped" => true,
            "ship_via" => "jne",
            "reference_no" => "$ordernumber",
            "tracking_no" => "",
            "deposit" => "0",
            "person_name" => "Lazada",
            "discount_type_name" => "Value",
            "discount_unit" => 0,
            "custom_id" => "",
            "tax_name" => "Tax 0%",
            "email" => "milleniabedding@gmail.com",
            "transaction_no" => "$orderitemid",
        ));

var_dump(altJSonEncode($inv));
```

[example](https://repl.it/EKJ1)

What we are doing here is we pass our array into the function when we first call it but not the second argument (so it has the default value). in our function if we detect the value of the current index in our for each loop is an array and if so we recall out function again sending the array we are up to and also passing in an updated value for `$tabNo`

this however still isn't perfect because

- all `$keys` are outputted, as such because `transaction_lines_attributes` is an array of arrays the key `0` is outputted for the first and only item
- in the example link 4 spaces are being outputted (not sure if that's the site's doing but even when i make then match, comparing to the example output the space number doesn't match.
- everything is treated as a string, as such integers like `quantity` will have `"` around the value. also if `tax` is false an empty string is returned (not sure why it's not a 0 since false = 0 and true = 1 and true still outputs 1, maybe it's just how boolean => string conversion works since an empty string `""` is also false in PHP)

but these little problems can be ironed with some more work. however both methods will require their own decode function rather than using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which to me seems more trouble than it's worth if you wanted json in the first place. `json_decode` works fine with the output of `json_encode` and vice versa